# Customize simple form radio buttons to match the theme markup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, simple-form

I’m using simple forms. The following line is what I have

```
=f.input :live_mode, as: :radio_buttons, label: false
```

which produces the following markup

```
<div class="form-group radio_buttons optional facility_live_mode"> . 
  <input type="hidden" name="facility[live_mode]" value="">
  <label class="radio">
    <label for="facility_live_mode_true">
      <input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="true" name="facility[live_mode]" id="facility_live_mode_true">
      Yes
    </label>
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <label for="facility_live_mode_false">
      <input class="radio_buttons optional" readonly="readonly" type="radio" value="false" checked="checked" name="facility[live_mode]" id="facility_live_mode_false">
      No
    </label>
  </label>
</div>
```

The wrapper `label` is the result of setting `config.item_wrapper_tag` in `simple_form.rb` to `:label` which matches the markup of the custom theme I’m using.

What I want to achieve is this

```
<input type="hidden" name="facility[live_mode]" value="">
<label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" value="true" name="facility[live_mode]" id="facility_live_mode_true">
  <span class="custom-control-label">Yes</span>
</label>
<label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input class="custom-control-input" readonly="readonly" type="radio" value="false" checked="checked" name="facility[live_mode]" id="facility_live_mode_false">
  <span class="custom-control-label">No</span>
</label>
```

but I have no idea how to go about doing this. Simple form config file provides a few options for customization but nothing that can produce the output that I need.

Is there something I can do to make this happen?

Comment: have you tried wrappers ? https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers

Comment: No luck with that. I ended up modifying CSS to match the rendered markup. Thanks!